# is it possible to renew a solaris license for an Sun ultra workstation

Tags: licensing, solaris, sun-workstation

I have an *old* Sun Ultra workstation from early 2000s, running Solaris with an IDE called sparcworks. I'm trying to revive it (I have some numerical analysis libraries I want to retrieve and re-use), but the software license has expired. Has anyone been in a similar situation, or have any suggestions as to whom I could contact to renew the license (since Sun microsystems no longer exists). Thanks v much

Comment: Its been a *very* long time, but I don't recall solaris having a time limited licence - or any OSes of that era for that matter. The *support* contract might have expired but that's not really useful if, well, your system is roughly old enough to drink. I also suspect our retrocomputing sister site might be a better resource for help on getting your hardware and software running..

Comment: Sun microsystems is now Oracle.  I know this might be illegal but have you tried backdating the system?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds more like they're interested in a license for "sparcworks" rather than Solaris itself. According to Wikipedia, this product is now known as [Oracle Developer Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Developer_Studio) after going through 7 name changes. So, you may want to contact Oracle about an updated license for that, with the hopes that it is still able to actually read the project information from your old projects.

SPARCWorks dates back to 1991-1992, so the modern version may not support the oldest projects any more.